# C# WinForms 'this.Controls.Find' in a separate class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to divide my program into classes to reduce clutter and increase readability.

In one of my methods, I need to find the location of a label on the screen.

`this.Controls.Find` worked before I moved everything into separate classes but it doesn't exist anymore because I am no longer executing it in the same class as the controls. I tried `Main.Controls.Find` (Main.cs is where my form is executed and set out) but this also didn't work and I got the error, "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.Controls'"

How do I reference the controls? Do I need to add an additional using statement?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: You need a reference to the Form object.  Easy inside the class, not so easy when you move it.  Consider passing it through the constructor.

Comment: Read more about [`Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) and creating object instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **reference** to the form, passed down to the newly introduced method (or class).

Before

```
public class Main : Form {

   public void Whatever() {
       ...
       this.Controls.Find(...);
   } 
}
```

After

```
public class Main : Form {

    public void Whatever() {
        ...
        new Helpers().HelperMethod( this );
    }
}

public class Helpers {

    public void HelperMethod( Form form ) {
        ...
        form.Controls.Find
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Main : Form {

    public void Whatever() {
        ...
        new Helpers( this ).HelperMethod();
    }
}

public class Helpers {

    private Form Form { get; set; }
    public Helpers( Form form ) {
        this.Form = form;
    }

    public void HelperMethod() {
        ...
        this.Form.Controls.Find
    }
}
```